# SMOOTH SHADING ARTIFACTING AFTER JOINING 2 MESHES

Tags: objects, faces, lighting, shadows, retopology

I made a separate object to model feet apart from the base mesh before joining it, making it one mesh. I then filled in all the faces between the two and as I did this I found that the smooth shading of the base mesh was interacting strangely with the joined mesh.

How do I fix this shading issue or is it a case of blender interacting with the model weirdly and its fine to export as is.

[image: Close up]

[image: Full screen]

Comment: Check for duplicate vertex there, there could be vertex fighting for dominance.

Comment: You deserve that for writing in all caps

Comment: Theres no vert double ups and all caps scares people into answering my question. So maybe I do deserve it

Comment: Select all in Edit mode and press Shift N in order to recalculate the normals?

Comment: @moonboots that was it thankyou so much. I've had this issue a lot so much appriciated

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps, it is the online equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). You can use the [edit] button below to change you text into regular case.

Comment: Why would it be considered rude or be harder to read?

Answer (score 0):

The normals are inverted (you can check if you enable the *Face Orientation* option in the *Viewport Overlays*, inverted faces will be displayed red instead of blue). Select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> in order to recalculate the normals.